# Muliti-line Log Message Filter in Log4j2.xml

Tags: java, regex, xml, log4j2

I am using regex filter(.asterisk User-Agent=BigIP Prober.asterisk ) in log4j2.xml to filter a specific log message (level=INFO) and printing it in file using rolling random file appendar. This filter is working fine for single line of log messages, when i try to do the same for Multi-line log messages it picks up only the regex line and not the entire message.

Log Message :

```
INFO 2016-08-09 08:05:00 TraceId=536906802.1470654766130752941 [qtp1386518493-290] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: - Jetty Connector Message - Port configured for it - 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage{
        Content-Length=558,
        User-Agent=BigIP Prober,
        Connection=keep-alive,
        Accept-Encoding=gzip,
        deflate,
        http.method=POSThttp.query.params={}}
```

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration >
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logpath">${env:MULE_BASE}/logs</Property>
    <Property name="appname">${env:MULE_APP}</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="${logpath}/1.log" 
        filePattern="${logpath}/1-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} TraceId=%X{svTraceId} [%t] %c:%L - %m%n" />
      <RegexFilter regex=".*User-Agent=BigIP Prober.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
      <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB"/>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" fileIndex="min"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile >
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="PerfRollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="${logpath}/2.log" 
        filePattern="${logpath}/2-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} TraceId=%X{svTraceId} [%t] %c:%L - %m%n" />
      <RegexFilter regex=".*User-Agent=BigIP Prober.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB"/>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" fileIndex="min"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile >
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>

    <Logger name="org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor" level="DEBUG"/>

    <Logger name="org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor" level="INFO" >
       <AppenderRef ref="PerfRollingRandomAccessFile" />    
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.bac" level="DEBUG" />
    <Logger name="com.bac.gwb.credit.lda.transformer.ReferenceValueTranslator" level="DEBUG" />


    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some code of yours. It's pretty hard to help with so little details about the actual programming.

Comment: @Tom added the log4j2 xml file and logger message